# query an object using uuid in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, uuid

I am using uuid for creating an id field which is primary key as below

```
import uuid

class User_Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

So whenever we save an object into the database it was saving as an UUID instance instead of string as below

```
user_profiles = User_Profile.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
print user_profiles
[UUID('193b6acc-2b78-4ddc-9ef8-632cde33ef74')]
```

now how to query it by using django ORM ? since it was not saving as a string i can't able to fetch it as below and getting an error

```
user_profile = User_Profile.objects.get(id='193b6acc-2b78-4ddc-9ef8-632cde33ef74')
```

### error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '193b6acc-2b78-4ddc-9ef8-632cde33ef74'
```

when i recieved this uuid as string from query params in Django, i also tried by converting it in to uuid from string as below and i got the error

```
import uuid
id = uuid.UUID('193b6acc-2b78-4ddc-9ef8-632cde33ef74')
user_profile = User_Profile.objects.get(id=id)
```

### error:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: uuid = numeric
LINE 1: ...ifications" FROM "tc_user_profile" WHERE "tc_user_profile"."id" = 33539211...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So finally how to query a uuid id field from django database ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I have tried this in my machine with database PostGres and it works,

```
>>> user = User_Profile.objects.create()
>>> user
<User_Profile: User_Profile object>
>>> user.id
UUID('d92c2280-4682-42ea-86c3-a1ed993c0638')
#copied the string of uuid only.
>>> id = 'd92c2280-4682-42ea-86c3-a1ed993c0638'
>>> User_Profile.objects.get(id=id)
<User_Profile: User_Profile object>

>>> import uuid
#converted the string into UUID format
>>> id = uuid.UUID(id)
>>> id
UUID('d92c2280-4682-42ea-86c3-a1ed993c0638')
>>> User_Profile.objects.get(id=id)
<User_Profile: User_Profile object>
```

If the problem still persists, try deleting the database and migrations and recreate it. The problem you are facing is not related to the database, it maybe something in your configuration.

Comment: which database are you using ? like i am using postgres

Comment: currently i just tested it on sqlite3, let me look into postgres as well.. I'll edit the answer shortly, after that.

Comment: I have done the same in postgres database too and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The field is a UUID so you should pass a UUID to query it. It is quite straight-forward if you see it:

```
import uuid
id = uuid.UUID('193b6acc-2b78-4ddc-9ef8-632cde33ef74')
user_profile = User_Profile.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: sorry i din't get you, with the above code, i am receiving an error `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 0):

i assume your using postgreSQL :

The Django docs say : When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a char(32).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/fields/

Comment: Yes i am postgres database,  but why i can't able to get the result and facing errors, what am i doing wrong in my above code

Comment: Wich version of Django did you use ?

Comment: I use Django==1.8.13

Comment: the version  1.8 have some issue with uuid and postgreSQL (PostgreSQLUUIDField -> UUIDField in this version), maybe you will need to upgrade your Django and make new migrations :(