# Django: filter returns empty result

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following table in my PostGreSQL database :

```
          workspace_role_id           | workspace_role_name 
--------------------------------------+---------------------
 3f76103f-732a-435a-a88f-737f4a6f1b87 | Owner
 c73b7c35-237e-4e13-8269-b259c2858b71 | Admin
 a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a | User
```

built from this Django model:

```
class WorkspaceRole(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("workspace_role_name",)

    workspace_role_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
    workspace_role_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {self.workspace_role_name}>"
```

And I want to retrieve the `workspace_role_name` from the ID.

However, the result of

```
WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_id="a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a")
```

is an empty queryset `<QuerySet []>`, but when I run

```
WorkspaceRole.objects.all()
```

I get the correct output: `<QuerySet [<WorkspaceRole: Admin>, <WorkspaceRole: Owner>, <WorkspaceRole: User>]>`

What am I doing wrong with my filter?

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: @LuSchink i would, but it did not, as I clarified in my response to it

Comment: What is the output of `print(repr(WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_name='User')[0].workspace_role_id))`?

Comment: @EndreBoth I get `UUID('a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a')` when I run this

Comment: And `WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_id=WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_name='User')[0].workspace_role_id)` still returns an emtpy queryset?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109047/query-an-object-using-uuid-in-django)...

```
import uuid
id = uuid.UUID('a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a')
WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_id=id)
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that but I still get an empty queryset `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: which ddbb are you using?

Comment: What is "ddbb"?

Comment: Database (ddbb for plural). Sorry for this one.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm using a PostGre SQL database

Comment: try this id = uuid.UUID('a61890fc1c294817868730786a5db17a')

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid

Comment: as you are using this field as primary key, you could probably do WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(id='a61890fc1c294817868730786a5db17a') or WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(pk='a61890fc1c294817868730786a5db17a'). Try it with the '-' also.

Comment: I tried the `pk` approach with each of the previous ways of formatting the id, but none worked O.o

Comment: last try: 
id = uuid.UUID('a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a')
WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(pk=id)

Comment: Already read that in some versions of Django there are some issues with primary_keys and UUIDFields...which version are you using?

Comment: I'm running 2.1.7

Comment: ... :/ weird. It's a problem with the data type you are sending in the queryset for sure... Let us know if you could solve it!

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering with a colleague, the solution was to use:

```
with in_database(my_db, write=True):
    id = uuid.UUID('a61890fc-1c29-4817-8687-30786a5db17a')
    WorkspaceRole.objects.filter(workspace_role_id=id)
```

Comment: So you are using several databases with the `dynamic_db_router` module? That's pretty essential information - great that you could solve it with your colleague.

Comment: Though only one db is used at a time, we are using that module, and I didn't know that until my colleague told me so

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old thread, but this is quite high in search results and I found the early seeds for the solution in this answers.

Simply put, this usually indicates a mis-match in types between the data in the db and the filters one is using. In my case for example I was using array of text instead of just text. Same as the answer above, where it was using a text for filtering a `uuid` field. So keep that in mind.